# Distance from intersection inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ and $Z$ closed subspaces of $X$. Suppose that $Y+Z$ is closed in $X$. Prove that there exists some $M > 0$ such that $\text{dist}(x, Y\cap Z) \leq M\left(\text{dist}(x, Y) + \text{dist}(x, Z)\right)$ for all $x\in X$.

**Attempt:** Since $Y$, $Z$ and $Y+Z$ are closed subspaces we know that $Y\times Z$ and $Y+Z$ are Banach spaces where $\lVert (y,z)\rVert_{Y\times Z} = \lVert y \rVert + \lVert z \rVert$. Define $T:Y\times Z \to Y + Z$ with $T(y,z) = y+z$. Clearly $T$ is surjective, linear and bounded operator. From the open mapping theorem we deduce that there exists some $M > 0$ such that for all $x \in Y+Z$ there exist $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$ such that $x=y+z$ and $\lVert y \rVert + \lVert z \rVert \leq M \lVert x \rVert$. I can't continue form there.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at brezis chapter 2.4